# Batch file close/kill a System Tray/systray program

Tags: batch-file, notification-area

I use a program for hosting multiple forms.

Each form leaves a systray program of said program. In Processing they all use the same same.

But Window wise/mouse over name while in tray they use the name of the form.

I can close all four at once but I wish to close certain ones with a batch file.

If anyone could help hat would be great.

Comment: By "systray", do you mean the taskbar (window list) or the notification area (icons in bottom-right corner, near the clock)?

Comment: I mean the Notification area.

Answer (score 2):

[NirCmd](http://nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) can close windows by title, class name, or hwnd.

```
nircmd win close title "Calculator"

nircmd win close class "IEFrame"
```

---

You can write your own program using `EnumWindows()` and `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL)`.

Comment: @Joey: Post that as a separate answer.

Comment: Having slight troubles with nircmd, I think it's because I'm not getting the right hwnd. Is that a bat I can right to determine that it's hwnd is? I assumed it was the name in the little hover over bubble.